summing across multiple columns named with a pattern with a condition on another column
Sample frame with data
df.100  <- data.frame(
  Rok = c( rep(2020, 12), rep(2021,12)),
  Msc = c(rep(seq(1,12,1),2)),
  WB_1 = c(rep(c(1,210,15),2), rep(c(11.3,18.9,210.1),2), rep(c(0.4,1.9,10.1),2), rep(c(25.4,13.9,31.1),2) ),
  WB_2 = c(rep(c(110,10,15),2), rep(c(11.3,19.9,410.1),2), rep(c(2.4,19.9,15.1),2), rep(c(45.4,31.9,31.6),2) ),
  WB_13 = c(rep(c(15.2,118,15.3),2), rep(c(0.4,1.9,10.1),2), rep(c(11.3,18.9,210.1),2), rep(c(45.4,19.9,37.1),2) )

)

When I needed to get a summary grouped by years, I used this solution:
df.100 <-  df.100 %>% 
  group_by(Rok) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(starts_with('WB'), ~ sum (.x, na.rm = T)),   
  )

And now I need to get a summary for individual years, but covering only 9 months (January to September)
df.100.9 <-  df.100 %>% 
  group_by(Rok) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(starts_with('WB'), ~ sum (.x, na.rm = T)),    
    # with condition
    across(starts_with('WB'), ~ sum (.[Msc <= 9], na.rm = T), .names = "9_{col}"), 
  )

Unfortunately, the values ​​for all 12 months are the same as for 9 months:
> df.100.9
# A tibble: 2 × 7
    Rok  WB_1  WB_2 WB_13 `9_WB_1` `9_WB_2` `9_WB_13`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2020  933. 1153.  322.     933.    1153.      322.
2  2021  166.  293.  685.     166.     293.      685.
> 

How do I correctly enter the months condition?

I have figured out it's due to the column names from the first sum you take, but I don't have an explanation for why that messes up the second sum yet. If you throw an "x", for example, at the front of the new names, those columns no longer interfere with the second across(starts_with('WB'), ~ sum(.... See the addition of .names = "x{col}".
df.100 %>% 
  group_by(Rok) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(starts_with('WB'), ~ sum (.x, na.rm = T), .names = "x{col}"),    
    # with condition
    across(starts_with('WB'), 
           ~ sum(case_when(Msc <= 9 ~ .x, .default = 0), na.rm = T), .names = "9_{col}") 
  )

# A tibble: 2 × 7
    Rok xWB_1 xWB_2 xWB_13 `9_WB_1` `9_WB_2` `9_WB_13`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2020  933. 1153.   322.    692.      711.      309.
2  2021  166.  293.   685.     95.2     184.      583 


You can swap the sum(case_when(... with sum(.x[Msc %in% 1:9], na.rm = T) if you like.

Also my solution uses case_when because I had been testing out multiple things. .[Msc <= 9], like you first had, works too.

Haha @AndreWildberg I was just posting my comment right as I saw yours :)
